# Loaders in fragment - will the fragment leak?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

consider [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) example from the android tutorial,

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

is  called `onActivityCreated`, giving the loader`CursorLoaderListFragment.this` instance, as far as i can tell there is no garuantee that the given fragment lifecycle is equal to the `Activity` hence `LoaderManager` lifecycle. So, if the fragment is removed while `Activity` is still living would it not cause a memory leak?

If yes, then how should they correct this example?

Comment: Nice observation, but AFAIK if the activity is still active while fragment is destroyed then loader should be destroyed with it because it was initialized in `onActivityCreated`.

Answer (score 2):

Loaders are destroyed and cleaned up when the bound Fragment or Activity destroys. i.e. If you pass Fragment instance to the `initLoader()`, then the Loader is destroyed when that Fragment instance is destroyed.

Reference:

https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832#.ai7whgsv4

> Loaders don’t stay around forever. They’ll be automatically cleaned up
>   when the requesting Activity or Fragment is permanently destroyed.
>   That means no lingering, unnecessary loads.